# How to add labels outside of polygons with a connecting line in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

In ArcMap, I essentially have a polygon of an island (Layer 1), with Layer 2 on top that shows the municipal boundaries within Layer 1.
Ideally, I'd like to label all of the Layer 2 polygons (with a number specified from my attribute table). I'd like the label to be outside of Layer 1 (in the free space on the map), with a line connecting to each polygon in Layer 2. Is there a way to do this without manually having to insert and move around the lines connecting to polygons?

Comment: I don't have access to my ArcMap at the moment but if you use the advanced text panel and select one of the callout options for your label,  turn on Maplex, Best (if you haven't already) and then adjust the feature weight settings and label priorities therein to keep labels off layer 1 and 2, and allow labels to be outside your polygon, you might get what you want.

Comment: Perhaps erase larger polygons by smaller.

Comment: Also Layer 1 needs to be given a high weight using the labeling tool, high interior and boundary weight.